# www.zqna.net scraping EL&U and SE content

Tags: discussion, copyrights, scraping

The site http://www.zqna.net/hokmohohoh/index.html appears to be reposting a lot of EL&U content (and it looks like other SE sites too). I can't see any proper attribution, or links back. Some pages say:

> Copyright 2011-2013 © Zqna

Their [About Us page](http://www.zqna.net/about.html) says:

> Zqna is a free question and answer website where you can get answers to your questions or you can help other people in the community by answering their questions.

Interestingly, they have a [Report Abuse page](http://www.zqna.net/abuse.html):

> We attach great importance to your advises, and what we build this site is for you.
>   Someone, neither you nor me post some bad infomation [sic] here, we appreciate you report it.
>   Please tell us your Contact Infomation [sic] if you want our feedback.
>   **If you want to remove question or answer, do tell us the link to it.**

Something like this happened on a Blogger blog not so long ago; here's the [relevant meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/is-http-englishqna-blogspot-com-violating-elu-or-your-copyright/).

Comment: If it isn't a blogger site, I'm not sure how to issue the takedowns. I'll check.

Comment: You could [sic] the whole abuse paragraph. Also, it seems like a lot of work to go to to set up a site like that (and all the scraping). Spend all that time on internet gambling...more profitable.

Comment: I've just used their Contact Us page to request the removal of all material attributed to me. We'll see what happens.

Comment: I just posted on their abuse page: __________

Referer: http://www.zqna.net/list/Mplungjan.html

Please immediately remove all content linked on the above link.

There is no mentioning of the origin of the posts which are stackexchange sites nor are there any links back to the original question or answer.

Comment: Not only is there no attribution, but the copyright notice added to it actively claims ownership and it's not in accordance with the license that does allow people to re-use material from these sites; so it's piracy and fraud, as well as plagiarism.

Comment: My takedown request appears to have worked; the only reference to "Andrew Leach" is in other people's content.

Comment: Drop the connections from the IPs spidering the SE content, request takedowns for the remaining material... Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

The whole http://www.zqna.net/ site appears to have been taken down.

Comment: Hip Hip, Hurray!

Comment: It appears the domain was parked on 18 February, which seems an odd thing to do. Perhaps someone complained to the original hosting company.