# www.rqna.net scraping EL&U and SE content

Tags: discussion, copyrights, scraping

The site `http://www.rqna.net/index-kmoh.html` appears to be reposting a lot of EL&U content with their own ads (and other SE sites too). I can't see any proper attribution, or links back. Some pages say:

> Copyright 2011-2013 © Rqna

Their About Us page (`http://www.rqna.net/about.html`) says:

> Rqna is a free question and answer website where you can get answers to your questions or you can help other people in the community by answering their questions.

Interestingly, they have a Report Abuse page (`http://www.rqna.net/abuse.html`):

> We attach great importance to your advises, and what we build this site is for you.
>   Someone, neither you nor me post some bad infomation [sic] here, we appreciate you report it.
>   Please tell us your Contact Infomation [sic] if you want our feedback.
>   **If you want to remove question or answer, do tell us the link to it.**

Something like this happened on a Blogger blog not so long ago; here's the [relevant meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/is-http-englishqna-blogspot-com-violating-elu-or-your-copyright/).

This looks like an exact copy of the recent zqna.net copycat; here's the [relevant meta from February](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/www-zqna-net-scraping-elu-and-se-content).

Comment: They like our advises, do they?

Comment: So too are [QandAsys](http://qandasys.info/what-do-you-call-the-little-plastic-dowel-like-protrusions-that-keep-two-pieces-of-plastic-together/). They’ve been reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187491).

Comment: You shouldn't link to them, having links from legitimate sites boosts their search engine ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) from a Community Manager at Stack Exchange:

> tl;dr: **Send all reports of SCRAPERs to `team@stackoverflow.com`.** Please include:
>
> - the URL of the copied post
> - the URL of the original post on SE
> - for high-rankers, the search string you used (and the name of the search engine, if not Google)
> - any other details you noticed and want to share, because you're awesome
>
> (This is the end of the tl;dr section.)
>
> I used to be the *de facto* curator of the two SCRAPER reporting posts here on Meta: [one for attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-stack-exchange-content-without-following-attribution-rules) and [another for ranking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-stack-exchange-content-copiers-here). The community was pretty good about using them, but like all list questions, they eventually turned into unmanageable messes that were hard to search. I've just saved all of the information posted there and deleted them.
>
> The community team has been working on improving its internal process for SCRAPERs behind the scenes, and now that I've joined the staff, I'm going to be in charge of it. By funneling everything through `team@stackoverflow.com`, we can organize our own efforts better, and as a side effect, we won't be giving Google-juice to the very sites that are being called out for being naughty.

Answer (score 10):

[Network policy has been updated as of Oct. 9 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/172958)

> tl;dr: **Send all reports of SCRAPERs to us via the contact form linked at the bottom of every page.** Please include:
>
> - the URL of the copied post
> - the URL of the original post on SE
> - for high-rankers, the search string you used (and the name of the search engine, if not Google)
> - any other details you noticed and want to share, because you're awesome

---

MSO, the main network meta site, has a [now obsolete -ed.] post [Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846/172958) where you can report such sites.

Comment: And, as expected, rqna.net is already there.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't bother trying to deal with the offending site directly. Despite what it might say on the *Report Abuse page*, they probably have no interest whatsoever in addressing complaints.

I suggest those people affected should follow [the instructions on this answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2154/2637) to a related question, and *file a DMCA complaint with Google*. I've done it a couple of times now (it's not much hassle).

Then just leave it to Google to take up cudgels on your behalf. Even if they don't directly force the site to be closed down, they can simply stop indexing it. And without that "oxygen of publicity", it's *Bye-bye scrapersite.com!*

Comment: I have tried but they said i can only complain if i am the copy-write holder.

Comment: @Ankit Sharma: In your case I think that's not an unreasonable response. So far as I can see, you've never asked nor answered any questions on ELU. In fact, as I write, the above comment seems to be your only contribution to the site. When I've filed DMCA complaints with Google, I've always cited at least one of ***my own*** answers (but I assume a *question* would do just as well, for those who haven't posted any answers).

Comment: I am not talking only for ELU but this site also copy content of Movies and TV and other SE sites too where i have participated. I am just a silent reader in ELU. Anyway i have reported this to SE in a mail.