# TechQues using English.SE content without proper attribution

Tags: discussion, copyrights, scraping

TechQues is reposting SE content but plastered with their own adverts. For example, this:

* `http://www.techques.com/question/32-69210/What-is-the-best-term-to-categorize-a-lolcat-image-and-text`

... is reposting content from this:

* [What is the best term to categorize a lolcat image and text?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69210/what-is-the-best-term-to-categorize-a-lolcat-image-and-text)

... without proper attribution. They include this footer:

> The content is from [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/), [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) and [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), 
>   and is licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/). Any advice please contact us.

Let's check off the [SE requirements](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) (found by clicking the link at the bottom of every page: "site design / logo © 2013 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)"):

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we **require** that you:
>
> 1. **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User** in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.

This is sort-of-but-not-really done. They say the content is from and link to Server Fault, Super User and Stack Overflow, but use English.SE content without saying so.

> 2. **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)

No links whatsoever to any english.stackexchange.com pages. There's a "View original post at" link to `http://questions/69210`. It works for SO questions, but they've taken content from English.SE and it's broken their site.

> 3. **Show the author names** for every question and answer

Done.

> 4. **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

Not done, similar to number 2. There are author links which work on SO content, but not with English.SE content. For example they point to `http://users/14157`.

Comment: There is a post at meta.SO for reporting such sites, it already [containst techques](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-stack-exchange-content-without-following-attribution-rules/166362#166362). (Maybe you can include this as an additional example, so far there are examples from tex.SE and judaism.SE.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll add a comment linking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Network policy has been updated as of Oct. 9 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/172958)

> tl;dr: **Send all reports of SCRAPERs to us via the contact form linked at the bottom of every page.** Please include:
>
> - the URL of the copied post
> - the URL of the original post on SE
> - for high-rankers, the search string you used (and the name of the search engine, if not Google)
> - any other details you noticed and want to share, because you're awesome

Attribution for this answer: originally posted by [Kevin](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14499/kevin) on Meta ELU as [an answer to "www.rqna.net scraping EL&U and SE content"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4077/94)

That said, I'm currently the SE staff member responsible for tracking SCRAPERs down, and I'm already aware of/working on TechQues. Thanks!