# What's being done to protect users' copyright?

Tags: discussion, support, copyrights, scraping

I previously asked this question [here on ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6966/mass-infringement-of-our-copyright) and on Meta too:

- [Mass infringement of our copyright](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6966/mass-infringement-of-our-copyright)

From the information that I got from the answers to that question from Meta and from ELU I [posted this answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6966/mass-infringement-of-our-copyright/6967#6967), which detailed the recommended way of going about reporting sites. However, since then the situation has changed considerably. The recommended actions don't address the problem outlined here, to any extent. This question has since been closed as a duplicate of that other question, but this question is specifically asking about SE's actions and responsibilities in relation to user's copyright of material posted on the ELU site. This question is necessary because the number of sites scraping SE users work without attribution is rapidly growing. Here is the original question.

---

Recently, I've seen more and more sites scraping content off SE EL&U and SE ELL. There are now so many that I can't keep up with them. I think we need a public ongoing page accessible on Meta where people can list websites that are nicking content without the full proper attribution, and where TPTB (the powers that be) can get back to us once the situation has been resolved.

However, I am now more interested in what SE is doing to ensure that it isn't neglecting its users. I'm a bit surprised that users seem to have to find this stuff and report it. I kind of feel that it's SE's responsibility to check on a regular basis who is scraping its members' (and its own) material. Shouldn't this be a routine practice on their part? If not, the agreement that they put forward to users is kind of useless. It amounts to - anyone can scrape your content without attributing it to you under the terms set out here on SE - so long as you don't report them to us. This seems unacceptable to me.

Some sites seem to be worse than others. Some link to SE, but not to the page they scraped the content from. Some list the username from here on SE but don't link to the page or mention SE or EL&U. Some just mention EL&U. There is definitely a range of violations going on. But it seems to me that SE has a duty of care towards its users - at least a moral one - to try to ensure that the terms set out on the site actually apply in a meaningful way.

What is the policy for checking up on who's nicking what from users here and from SE in general?

Here's what I found in 20 mins.

**List of scrapers**

- [http://htmlasks.com](http://htmlasks.com/the_subject_of_an_interrogative_sentence)
- [http://www.jhedzworld.com/](http://www.jhedzworld.com/2015/10/19/what-part-of-speech-is-down-in-put-your-pencils-down-english-stackexchange-com-jhedzworld/)
- [http://english.itsprite.com/english-languagehow](http://english.itsprite.com/english-languagehow-can-i-reliably-and-accurately-identify-the-passive-voice-in-writing-or-speech/)
- [http://asiw.net](http://asiw.net/more/694539_9/grammar-What-is-the-correct-verb-that.html)
- [http://trello.info](http://trello.info/question/view/en/YUhSMGNEb3ZMMlZ1WjJ4cGMyZ3VjM1JoWTJ0bGVHTm9ZVzVuWlM1amIyMHZjWFZsYzNScGIyNXpMekkzT1RjM055OTBhR1V0WlhSNWJXOXNiMmQ1TFc5bUxYUnZMWEJ5YjNabExXUnZkV2Rv)
- [http://pr8x.com/english/questions/](http://pr8x.com/english/questions/290399/aspiration-of-plosives-in-final-position-and-word-boundaries.html)
- [http://newtips.co/english/questions](http://newtips.co/english/questions/290976/the-superhero-is-you-vs-the-superhero-are-you.html)
- [http://possessive66.rssing.com](http://possessive66.rssing.com/chan-46700668/latest.php)

Comment: For reference, here is the [canonical MSE post on this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/273503), with guidance from the SE team on how to handle and report scrapers, as well as what the limitations are in dealing with them.

Comment: Related: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/http-english-seeore-com-scraping-elu-content, http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4070/www-rqna-net-scraping-elu-and-se-content, http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/www-zqna-net-scraping-elu-and-se-content

Comment: Can I suggest that you **don't** link here, because links increase the Google ranking of the target site (especially since this one is highly-placed) and we don't really want that!

Comment: @AndrewLeach Where can they be listed? I'm kind of tempted to think that in that case, SE might do something about it faster! But I'll move them if you can tell me where to. If you want to report them all on the SE form, I'm quite happy for you to do that?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'll remove the links for the time being, but something needs to be done about this.

Comment: Listing here is fine; it's the linking which is counterproductive. Note that SE can automatically produce links and you really need backticks.

Comment: @AndrewLeach But if you list www.newtips.com it comes up as a link ... :(

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'l try and sort that out then when I get back.

Comment: So if I understand this post correctly, what you're saying is that answers we give on ELU are copy and pasted to another website.  Correct?

Comment: @michael_timofeev they are copycat websites, they look like genuine English language Q&A websites but the difference being that they contain "our" questions and answers. I don't know how they do it but days after posting a question you will see that same question replicated elsewhere.

Comment: So a question I posted is there, or an answer I posted is there...but no name?

Comment: @michael_timofeev sometimes the author is credited, but more often than not it 's anonymous.

Comment: I checked one of the websites...there is plenty of advertisement on it...so they are using SE content to make a profit.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I thought most Stack Exchange links are nofollow by default. This page seems to suggest that the only exceptions currently are for some users' " 'official web site' link in their profile": [Can we not rel=nofollow links in profile About Me for users with 3000+ rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/can-we-not-rel-nofollow-links-in-profile-about-me-for-users-with-3000-rep)

Comment: And this seems to suggest that attempts to make some post-links followed were declined: [Remove nofollow on links at a certain age](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/remove-nofollow-on-links-at-a-certain-age/51156#51156) Edit: never mind, the [update here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/remove-nofollow-on-links-deemed-reputable) says *some* links are not no-follow if the post meets certain vague requirements, including score.

Comment: @sumelic I don't think it matters to Google if the link is nofollow or not: it's a link, so the content it points to must be worth something.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: my impression was that the whole point of nofollow links is to indicate to Google that that is not the case. I don't know that much about SEO though so I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: [Google respect "nofollow"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think you need to make that a general principle for all questions about scraping. Every question about scraping that I've ever seen includes a link to the sites in question ... If anything putting all the links in one post makes it less likely that they will all be visited. (I'm going to put them in, I'm just making the point. Do you have any insight into an answer for this question?

Comment: The answer to the question is [on M.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do). And while Google may (or may not; who knows?) respect nofollow, others won't.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's a useful Q&A, but it *doesn't* explain what SE is doing to protect users' copyright, and it doesn't allow for an easy drop off point. Nor does it tell people which sites are using their stuff without accrediting them. So, in short it doesn't *really* answer this question at all. And it doesn't respond to the request for an open page.

Comment: If it's a general SE question, it needs to be asked on M.SE, and I'm afraid it's likely to be closed as a dupe of that one. I would advise being **very** and **explicitly** specific about the question; but I suspect the answer is that the licence is held by the original author who must protect his own copyright (and SE respect CC-BY-SA).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I may have to withdraw my posts then.

Comment: Actually this question is doing _two_ things: (1) asking what SE is doing to protect copyrights, and (2) accumulating a list of sites which are copying SE content in violation of the copyright. Part (2) is [already covered on Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/273503), and I think you're more likely (or at least no less likely) to get a response by posting scraper sites there, not here. But the Meta SE question does not cover part (1), so if I may offer a suggestion, I think it would be useful to limit this question to that part only.

Comment: @DavidZ I get the point, but not exactly. If everyone uses that form, then the rest of the users here don't know how many or which sites are using their stuff. They also don't know which sites have already been reported, and there's less pressure for S.E. to do something serious about it. In any case it's much better for everything to be transparent and for people to be informed. To a certain extent the form over there is a carpet under which to sweep the problem. Also it takes time. Listing a site here is easy to do and takes a second. If S.E. then want to do anything about it they can.

Comment: @Araucaria oh, right, I'd forgotten that they replaced the previous version (in which they asked you to post the site in an answer) with the current contact form. So I see the benefit of also publicly posting scrapers here. But (I think) the fact is, the people at SE are unlikely to pay attention to this post. There is little pressure for them to do anything about it either way, but filling out the form has the advantage of semi-actively bringing someone's attention to the scraper site, whereas this does not.

Comment: @DavidZ I agree. I've already done about four of those forms though. Can't be bothered to do any more ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mass infringement of our copyright](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6966/mass-infringement-of-our-copyright)

Comment: @sampablokuper This is the follow up question from that question because the situation has deteriorated since then!

Comment: @Araucaria, maybe merge the questions, to keep the relevant discussion all in one place?

Comment: @sampablokuper No way. Firstly, the more places this problem gets seen the better for users of SE. Secondly the questions are entirely different. The first is about how to go about reporting scraper sites who abuse the license. This one is about what SE's doing themselves to protect their users' copyright. The answer to this particular question is that they're doing nothing at all if it isn't reported. Otherwise they're just following through with stuff if they a) get it reported, but b) do it more urgently if it affects SE's google listing. This is a separate question and answer altogether.

Comment: @sampablokuper But the current link here is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

From the footer of this (any every Stack Exchange) site:

> user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

I checked a couple of the sites you linked, and somewhere on the page they all list the source of the content with a link to the original question.

- Are they unethical? Yes.
- Can we stop it? Probably.
- Is it infringing copyright? Probably not.

Comment: I've reactivated the links. I might be wrong, but starting with the first link there, maybe you'd like to tell us where the original author is credited and where the link is to the original question?

Comment: Scratch what I said, one of them autoredirects to some wierd porn sites. Nuke them from orbit!

Comment: How is it unethical if the creative commons license allows them to use the content in any way they want as long as they attribute it?

Comment: @desbest: To the extent that they're skimming money off the top without adding any value, they're unethical. That's the situation with most scrapers, legal and illegal alike. CC doesn't attempt to define added value (partly for philosophical, partly for practical reasons), but confusing legality with ethicality is a grave error.

Comment: @desbest Because they *aren't* attributing it. None of the listed sites list the source of the questions and  answers.